# Use OCX without registering it

Tags: .net, com, ocx, regfreecom

Is it possible to use an ocx (ActiveX Control) on a winform (probably adding it programatically) without first having the ocx registered with regsrv32?

What I'm trying to achieve is to enable xcopy installation. I've had the "AxInterop.*.dll" and "Interop.*.dll" file generated from my dev machine.

I've seen the possibility of calling a COM dll without first registering it ([ProSysLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/ProSysLib2.aspx?fid=1524721&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2659721&fr=28#xx2659721xx), according to the author, but I haven't tested it yet), since ocx is also COM based, thus I assume that there must be some way to do that as well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  You must assume your application will only be deployed on Windows XP (or Windows Server 2003) or later, and then you can use what is called 'registration free COM' to make this happen.

Essentially what you do is create a manifest file for the ActiveX control DLL so the Windows loader & COM DLL's know what its registration is without having to put that in the registry.

A walkthrough of what to do is in this article on MSDN:
[Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

"Step 6" and "Step 7" in that article contain *everything* you will need.

I just tried this out on one of my own C# programs that uses a Microsoft ActiveX grid control (the old "MS Flex Grid") and it works just fine. Make sure you create a manifest file for both your application and the COM DLL, and substitute the appropriate GUIDs in the right places. You may need to use OLEVIEW to dig out the right IDs to use from the ActiveX DLL if you don't have them handy.

Comment: Be aware it can randomly cause crashes on Windows XP >:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617253/is-anyone-successfully-using-registration-free-com-with-net-components

Comment: The tools [Make My Manifest](https://github.com/froque/Make-My-Manifest) and [Unattended Make My Manifest](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) automate much of this process.

Comment: Does this work on Linuxes?

Answer (score 5):

Be warned that apparently using registry-free COM for COM components authored in .NET can randomly cause crashes on Windows XP!

Links: [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617253/is-anyone-successfully-using-registration-free-com-with-net-components) where I learned this, Microsoft knowledgebase [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943232) referred to in that question. There is a hotfix but you aren't allowed to redistribute it.

Answer (score 3):

It is even a lot simplier in Visual Studio: just go to References, find positions created by your ocx (there should be 2, AxSomething and Something) and set for both of them Isolated: true in their properties. No manifestes, no code.
You should now distribute your exe with dll file containing ocx. On your developement machine, the ocx can be registered.

Comment: Isolated Property doesn't appear in my case.BTW there is a reference to system's Stdole lib, and this one has the Isolated property. Scanning the csproj file, I see it's a <COMReference> (with Guid, VersionMajor, VersionMinor,... attributes), instead of the other 2 that are <Reference Include="AxInterop.SomethingLib"> and
<Reference Include="Interop.SomethingLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
I tried LOTS of combinations to get this to work, like changing those 2 to COMReferences, giving them Guid, VersionMajor, VersionMinor attributes, but no solution till now

Answer (score 2):

Now, there is a copy of the  unreachable click site solution: mmm4vb6.atom5.com/yes-update-0-12-5479.html#c on web archive:  http://web.archive.org/web/20140828233304/http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/yes-update-0-12-5479.html

and the context of:

## **Make My Manifest**

Sunday, April 7, 2013

### Yes, An Update

While I am not as active using VB6 for day to day work anymore, along the way my colleagues and I have needed to repackage some existing applications after bug fixes and just to cope with the changing Windows landscape.

We've made a few changes since the last version posted and things look good.  I decided to post this update but please note that it has not been tested as thoroughly as most of the earlier releases!

So be sure to test your MMM'ed applications packaged using MMM 0.12 thoroughly before releasing them.

See the Change Log (Related\MMMChangeLog.txt) for details.  Here are the notable changes though:

Another attempt to improve/correct the DPI-Aware node of the manifest.
A change to TLB handling to prevent them from being included.  TLBs are not normally needed at runtime.  If you do need to include them add them yourself via Add Files or copy them to the target folder afterward.
An attempt to cope with Microsoft patches that ended up causing "duplicate" coClass entries in MMM's manifests.
Better (we hope) handling of non-creatable classes contained in some VB6-supplied OCXs.
I hope this addresses some concerns you too may be facing in these areas.  And of course I hope this version doesn't break anything or make things worse in some way.

Get the new version by downloading:

[MMM-0-12](http://web.archive.org/web/20140828233304/http://home.comcast.net/%7Ebvocs/miscdls/MMM-0-12-src.zip)

Posted at Sunday, April 7, 2013 02:59 PM
...

Comment: the source code of Make My Manifest Version 0.12 https://github.com/froque/Make-My-Manifest

Answer (score 0):

After 10 hours of searching how to run VB6 app with OCX on Win7 without registering it and admin rights, I found few click solution here : http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/yes-update-0-12-5479.html#c

Need to check Embed Manifest to make it work. Works as charm !

I do post solution here, because I also found this question here.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always **quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.**

Answer (score 0):

I converted an ocx to dll by

- opening the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"
- calling "tlbimp filename.ocx"

then I imported the resulting filename.dll as reference in my project.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but it does not work