# Can a DLL call a .NET DLL?

Tags: .net, interop, clr

Can a native DLL call a .NET DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to use managed c++

Comment: Exactly.  What we do is create a thin wrapper with standard extern "C" exports in Managed C++, then write the real code in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Without using COM, you have to write a C++/CLI wrapper.  Your native code that includes the header file of your wrapper needs to be compiled with /clr (common language runtime support).

Just for curiosity, why not using COM interop?  Check out the regasm.exe and tlbexp.exe tools.

Comment: Because I am not familiar with COM and will do everything I can to avoid learning it :)

Comment: COM also suffers from the nasty DLL hell problem due to global registration. It's possible to do registration-free COM but the documentation is confusing and there are bugs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617253/is-anyone-successfully-using-registration-free-com-with-net-components

Answer (score 1):

You need something to make the managed world and the unmanaged world work together. If you don't want to use COM, you can create wrapper classes in C++/CLI.

Here is an article that can get you started: [.NET to C++ Bridge](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx).