# OCX registration free

Tags: c#, com, manifest, ocx, side-by-side

I would like to write a simple windows form application, I'd like to use a 3rd party
file, but it is deny to write in registry. 
I've tried to add this `ocx control` to project, but the Visual Studio runs the `regsvr32`, so it has been registered.

Is it possible to use registration free activation, or I have to register in any case?

Comment: VS does *not* run regsvr32 on references you add.  Doesn't matter anyway, it only needs to work properly on that other machine.  Just set the Isolated property of the reference to True.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I would like to make a simple proof of concept, so I've downloaded just a first ocx control, what I've found. 
Firstly I would like to build a solution, and after that I would like to make a wrapper for this `ocx controls`, but at this point when I'm using an `aximp` tool, I have to register to registry this `ocx`. I've tried it with `tlbimp` command, but it didn't make `RCW` (runtime callable wrapper).
Can I make a wrapper without registry writing, or I have to make a virtual machine, which will create this RCW dlls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use OCX without registering it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234726/use-ocx-without-registering-it)